Bullish bar high higher than high of 2 bearish bars and vice versa
I would like help with a code in pine editor that detect a bullish bar which high is higher than 2 previous bearish candles with the close of the bullish bar higher than the open of the previous bearish bar. And the opposite with a bearish bar.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question will be much better received if you make an attempt yourself and show us where exactly your attempt falls short of your desired outcome. "Write this code for me" is often considered too broad a request here.
